# To input data like table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need meta data of fields.
like this code.

```
var fields =  [
  { code: 'name',     display: 'Name',             isActive: true },
  { code: 'tel',      display: 'Telephone Number', isActive: true },
  { code: 'mobile',   display: 'Mobile',           isActive: true },
  { code: 'email',    display: 'Email address',    isActive: true },
  { code: 'nickname', display: 'Nickname',         isActive: true },
];
```

There are many fields so I'm tired.
How to write without property name?
I want to a flow like next code.

```
var fieldsString = "
code        | display            | isActive
'name'      | 'Name'             | true
'tel'       | 'Telephone Number' | true
'mobile'    | 'Mobile'           | true
'email'     | 'Email address'    | true
'nickname'  | 'Nickname'         | true
'tel'       | 'Mobile'           | true
";

var tableData = new TableData(fieldsString);
var fields = tableData.getData();
```

Who knows a format for table data like above code?

Comment: In your second example all you need to do is split the string at |, set up a for loop that increments by 3, build the necessary inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two dimensional array would do the trick

```
var keysArray = ['code','display','isActive'];
var fieldArray = [
  ['name'    , 'Name'            , true ],
  ['tel'     , 'Telephone Number', true ],
  ['mobile'  , 'Mobile'          , true ],
  ['email'   , 'Email address'   , true ],
  ['nickname', 'Nickname'        , true ],
  ['tel'     , 'Mobile'          , true ]
];
```

then simply use the map function of arrays to convert to the object based representation  [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var fields=fieldArray.map(function (current) {
  var tempobj = {};
  for(var i=0, len=keyArray.length; i<len; i++){
    tempobj[keyArray[i]] = current[i];
  }
  return tempobj;
}
```

You could make this even more concise by replacing the tempobj and the for loop with a call to reduce [Array.protoype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Good idea! Thank you!